# Neo4j query works in neo4j desktop but not python driver

Tags: python, neo4j

My code below returns an empty list for `result`. However when I paste the query in neo4j desktop and replace $keyword with `"power control"`, it runs and returns a series of keyword frequency by year. I have no issue with authenticating to the database as far as I know, no errors. Anything seems out of ordinary?

```
from neo4j import GraphDatabase


class KeywordPublicationFrequency:

    def __init__(self, uri, user, password):
        self.driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, auth=(user, password))

    def close(self):
        self.driver.close()

    def get_publication_frequency(self, keyword):
        with self.driver.session() as session:
            result = session.read_transaction(self._create_and_return_query, keyword)
            print(result)
            for record in result:
                print("Year: ", record['Year'], "Publications: ", record['Publications'])

    @staticmethod
    def _create_and_return_query(tx, keyword):
        query = """
        MATCH (k:KEYWORD {name: $keyword})-[:LABEL_BY]-(p:PUBLICATION)
        RETURN p.year as Year, count(p) as Publications
        ORDER BY Year ASC
        """
        result = tx.run(query, keyword=keyword)
        return list(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    kp_frequency = KeywordPublicationFrequency("bolt://localhost:7687", "my username", "my password")
    kp_frequency.get_publication_frequency("power control")
    kp_frequency.close()
```

Comment: At initial glance, nothing jumps out at me as wrong. But, you may want to adjust your database to be consistent with Neo4j style guide. It doesn't matter to the functionality, of course, but it makes the cypher more readable (e.g., node labels in camel-case).
https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/styleguide/  


...unless that *is* your issue. Does the database have `Keyword` instead of `KEYWORD`?

Comment: Also, note that `read_transaction` is now deprecated in favor of `execute_read` (same with `write_transaction` vs `execute_write`). https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/current/api.html#neo4j.Session.execute_read

Answer (score 0):

Your data might be on a different database on the same neo4j server. If yes, then change the code like below:

```
def __init__(self, uri, user, password, databasename):
    self.driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, auth=(user, password), database=databasename)
```

Then

```
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        kp_frequency = KeywordPublicationFrequency(
            "bolt://localhost:7687", "my username", "my password", "my dbname")
```